# how to inline-flex two text elements, but wrap only overflowing text, not whole element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to `inline-flex` two text elements in one line, but the problem is, when the text is overflowing, whole overflowing element wraps to next line. (Which is the correct behavior).

But my goal is to wrap only overflowing part of the text, not whole element. Like it's only one element overflowing.

Is it possible? Thank you.

```css
.wrapper{
  background: grey;
  padding:1rem;
  width:75%;
}

.parent{
  background:white;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.first{
  font-weight:bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <p class="first">Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse.</p>
    <p class="second">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you want basically two columns, the first p element in the first one etc and for the two p elements to wrap individually.

This snippet removes the flex-wrap from the parent to achieve this.

```css
.wrapper{
  background: grey;
  padding:1rem;
  width:75%;
}

.parent{
  background:white;
  display:inline-flex;
  /* flex-wrap:wrap;*/
}

.first{
  font-weight:bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <p class="first">Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse.</p>
    <p class="second">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have explained it wrong. My goal is to display two p elements in a row, but when the second element is overflowing, wrap to the next line only overflowing part of the text, not whole p element.

Comment: So if the first element isn't overflowing but the second element it you want the overflowing text from the second element to go where? Starting at the left hand side (ie under the first p element) or .... And what if the first element is overflowing? Perhaps you could include a diagram in your question? Thanks.